# Is there really anything Damascene about Vitus Bering and Bishop Innocent of Irkutsk?

Tags: грамматика

As I read it, this passage from O.E.Naumova's "Irkutskaya Eparkiya" (1996) says that the bishop of Irkutsk sent some monks on [Vitus Bering's Second Kamchatka Expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Northern_Expedition). The word Damascene or its derivatives come up twice, but it doesn't seem to be about steel nor cloth nor Middle Eastern people.

Who or what here was of Damascus?

[image: book text]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Дамаскин* is a Russian last name, one of a large class of so called "seminary surnames" (*семинарские фамилии*) that many Russians bear.

Those surnames were given upon graduation from the seminary to members of clergy coming from lower estates (peasantry, urban commoners etc.), who were originally entitled to no surname or whose original surnames were not deemed befitting a man of the cloth.

The most common seminary surnames originate from the Christian holidays (*Успенский, Преображенский, Троицкий, Введенский* etc.) or the saints' names (*Богословский, Борисоглебский, Анненский*), but there is a large strata of surnames originating from places and names mentioned in the Bible (*Голгофский, Елеонский, Иорданский*), or just seminary nicknames translated to Latin or Greek (*Велосипедов* "one with fast feet", *Собриевский* "a sober one", *Аедоницкий* "nightingale") etc.

*Дамаскин* is just one of those names<strike>, which was given either to the member of Bering's expedition or one of his ancestors upon graduation from the seminary</strike>.

**Update:**

Upon further reading I've discovered that name mentioned in the book is most probably not the last name *Дама́скин* but rather the monastic name *Дамаски́н* (Damascene).

All above about the seminary surnames still holds, it just does not apply to the person in question :)

Comment: Is it unclear from the text which one of the monks was so named?

Comment: @AaronBrick: I'm afraid I don't follow your question. Damaskin was a priest monk, a member of Bering's expedition, and Bishop Innocent ordered Damaskin to spread the good word among the Kamchadal. The text is quite clear about that.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't parse it as a fully formed person's name until you explained. The other monks all have given and/or monastic names.

Comment: wrt your Update: did you find another source that clarifies that it was a monastic name and not a seminary surname? also, how does the emphasis distinction reveal which is which?

Answer (score 4):

Дамаскин is the name(or a surname ) of the monk from Valaam monastery who was invited by V.Bering to his expedition among six monks. The surname originated from the ancient city Damask (the citizen of Damask ). The most famous bearer of this surname was Иоанн Дамаскин, who came from that city.

Comment: Please reveal your source for the reference to Valaam monastery and the number six. I only count four monks, and a different monastery, mentioned in the passage.

Comment: Neue Seite 32
vostlit.info›Документы›…1720-1740/Bering/briefe…
Беринг, со своей стороны, выполняя императорский указ ... священниках: иеромонахе Феофилакте и иеромонахе Дамаскине

Comment: Can't find the second one, sorry.

Comment: Another source says Соловки.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `Дамаскин` is the surname of a member of Bering's expedition (a hieromonk), and has nothing to do with Damascus in this context (at least without looking at the surname's etymology). Keep in mind that in Russian, unlike English, proper adjectives referring to places are never capitalized (with the exception of being included in institution names, e.g. `Дамасский университет`), so a regular reference to something Damascene would be `дамасский` or `дамасская (сталь)`.

Comment: That's a very helpful point about the capitalization.